# finding button with similar href

Tags: python, selenium

a particular button (which allows me to jump to the second page) has a href

```
inputHref = /letsdeal?sectionLoadingID=m_timeline_loading_div_1485935999_0_36_timeline_unit%3A1%3A00000000001483240170%3A04611686018427387904%3A09223372036854775803%3A04611686018427387904&unit_cursor=timeline_unit%3A1%3A00000000001483240170%3A04611686018427387904%3A09223372036854775803%3A04611686018427387904&timeend=1485935999&timestart=0&tm=AQBwkKKSIKOhqAju&refid=17
```

and if i click on this button a second page open ups and a button (which takes me to the third page) has a href

```
inputHref = /letsdeal?sectionLoadingID=m_timeline_loading_div_1485935999_0_36_timeline_unit%3A1%3A00000000001482227114%3A04611686018427387904%3A09223372036854775798%3A04611686018427387904&unit_cursor=timeline_unit%3A1%3A00000000001482227114%3A04611686018427387904%3A09223372036854775798%3A04611686018427387904&timeend=1485935999&timestart=0&tm=AQBwkJZSIKOhqAju&refid=17
```

Both Href are different in the end part but similar in the start. How can i locate both of these buttons using the XPATH using one formula just like the following code.

```
 extendButton = driver.wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                        (By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'"+inputHref + "')]")))
```

Comment: Could you also show the complete HTML representations of both links - including the link texts and other attributes? There could be other options. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a partial match using `contains()`:

```
//a[contains(@href, "letsdeal")]
```

Or:

```
//a[contains(@href, "/letsdeal")]
```

Or, with a *CSS selector*:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[href*=letsdeal]")
```

Note that I don't know how unique the "letsdeal" substring is on your page and whether it is used in other href attribute values.